# couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'

Tags: laravel, terminal, zsh

Im trying to start up Homestead 2.0 for a Laravel app however every time I run

```
homestead up
```

I get the output

```
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `expand_path': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `expand_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `user_data_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:16:in `user_plugins_file'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:27:in `instance'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

What does `couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding`~' mean and how can I fix it? I'm using Oh-my-zsh as a shell.

Comment: hrm... homestead should catch this & output meaningful/useful message

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Search your php.ini with this commands: `php --ini`

In your php.ini file, set `variables_order = "EGPCS"`.

Thats it.

Comment: This worked for me as well. EGPCS is the default in PHP but for some reason it was set differently in my php.ini.

Comment: Worked for me on Debian Jessie.. the php.ini file that had to be modified was /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: My php.ini file is located in /etc/php.ini. When I try to edit the file, it says it's locked and will only allow me to make a duplicate. How did you go about editing the file?

Comment: @shimizu Do this: `sudo chmod +w /etc/ini` . Then you can edit it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having the same issue. As a work-around, you can add

`ENV["HOME"] = "/Users/your-user-name"`

to  the file

```
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-*version*/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb
```

right underneath `require "tempfile"` to get it up and running

Comment: It looks like this doesn't allow one to access the current homestead box but creates a new one in its place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify HOME environmental variable for your shell. Now your home dir is being found by checking ~ which always returns your default home dir i.e. cd ~ takes you to home dir.

Answer (score 0):

The '~' shortcut in shell stands for the home folder for a user. For example, on OSX, if the user name is gael, the ~ is expanded (replaced) by the path which is /Users/gael.

For the second part of your question, may try to set HOME before launching it :
    export HOME=/Users/gael

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answers by @michal.z & @gael

I had this problem and I am able to successfully

```
echo $HOME
```

which returns
/home/my-username
but I still got the error :-/

Anyway. I chose to follow @Adunahay s advice and I manually added the environment variable to the shared_helpers.rb file.